# Generate GUID from a string that is not in guid format

Tags: c#, parsing, .net-4.0, guid

I would like to generate a GUID from the input string. Let's say I have guid received from the user which is

```
81a130d2-502f-4cf1-a376-63edeb000e9f
```

so I can do:

```
 Guid g = Guid.Parse("81a130d2-502f-4cf1-a376-63edeb000e9f");
```

which is going to parse successfully.

But how to make user's life easier and allow to input:

```
81a130d2502f4cf1a37663edeb000e9f
```

which is without dashes, and still convert it to guid.

If I will try to use the same method it's gonna throw the exception complaining on the missing dashed in the guid format.

Any ideas?

Comment: How will having to input an unreadable horrible amount of hex chars (a GUID) actually improve users' lives? I really REALLY doubt this...

Comment: well, in the app I am writing user will get GUID of their device in this format 81a130d2502f4cf1a37663edeb000e9f. Then user will have to re type this value in another textbox, so I don't want them to count at which position dashed has to be inserted

Comment: it just different design of my app that needs to have this format

Comment: then create a proper UI (composed of 5 textboxes separated with dashes) - something like [this](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC118506.png)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try

```
Guid.ParseExact("81a130d2502f4cf1a37663edeb000e9f", "N");
```

Answer (score 24):

The in addition to `ParseExact` (with `"N"` as the second argument), you could instead use the overload of the `Guid` constructor that accepts a string; it allows you to specify your value without dashes as well.

```
Guid g = new Guid("81a130d2502f4cf1a37663edeb000e9f");
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.parseexact.aspx) method:

```
Guid.ParseExact("81a130d2502f4cf1a37663edeb000e9f","N")
```